# Не запускается MonoDevelop в Unity 2017.4

Tags: unity3d

Переустанавливал разные версии, включая gtk-sharp-2.12.45.msi все равно при клике на сценарий выскакивает это окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стоит Windos 7 SP1, NET 4.5

Comment: переходили по ссылке? скачивали и устанавливали, что предлагает?

Comment: да, он предлагает скачать  gtk-sharp-2.12.45.msi

Comment: да, это базовые компоненты для него. И всё равно не работает?

Comment: да, я уже написал же. может ещё что-то нужно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее:
1. Установите [последнюю версию .Net с сайта Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49981)
2. Переустановите Unity
3. Установите [GTK# for .net](http://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/)

Comment: последняя версия .Net с сайта Microsoft помогла